# Can tensorflow automatically create a unique run directory?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorboard

Tensorboard can visualize several runs of a tensorflow graph, by storing each run in a sub-directory of the logging directory.
For instance, [the documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tensorboard/README.md#runs-comparing-different-executions-of-your-model) provides this example:

```
experiments/
experiments/run1/
experiments/run1/events.out.tfevents.1456525581.name
experiments/run1/events.out.tfevents.1456525585.name
experiments/run2/
experiments/run2/events.out.tfevents.1456525385.name
/tensorboard --logdir=experiments
```

To start the next run (run3), a new directory should then be passed to the SummaryWriter constructor:

```
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('experiments/run3/', sess.graph)
```

where the directory is the top-level logging directory (experiments) and a unique ID (run3).

Is there a way to automatically create a new unique run ID?
Sequential integer IDs would be good, so would time-based IDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check in python what are the directories existing in `experiments` and create a new one with an incremented number.

If the list is empty, we start at `run_01`.

```py
import os

previous_runs = os.listdir('experiments')
if len(previous_runs) == 0:
    run_number = 1
else:
    run_number = max([int(s.split('run_')[1]) for s in previous_runs]) + 1

logdir = 'run_%02d' % run_number
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(os.path.join('experiments', logdir), sess.graph)
```

I used `"%02d"` to have names like: `run_01, run_02, run_03, ... run_10, run_11`.